# Jmdns not resloving service

Tags: android, jmdns

I followed the example that comes with JmDNS. My code is as below!

```
jmdns = JmDNS.create();
jmdns.addServiceListener("_nmx._tcp.local.",new ServiceListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void serviceResolved(ServiceEvent event) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                Log.e("called","serviceResolved");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void serviceRemoved(ServiceEvent event) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void serviceAdded(ServiceEvent event) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                Log.e("called","serviceAdded");
                                Log.e("val:",event.getType()+":"+event.getName());
                                ServiceInfo info = event.getInfo();
                            //  Log.e("name",info.getHostAddress());
                                jmdns.requestServiceInfo(event.getType(), event.getName());

                            }
                        });
                    }
```

I never see `"called serviceResolved"` log message. But i see `service added` log message. Is there anything else should i do to resolve the service to get the ip of the host?

Comment: Is the method serviceAdded called?

Comment: Yes. `serviceAdded` has been called but `event.getinfo` returns null, beacuse to get info, like host address & port, the service should be resolved, that's why i called `jmdns.requestServiceInfo`. But nothing i get

Comment: Are you coding for android? What is your setup? Maybe its a firewall issue.

Comment: My network is backed by firewall. how come i ensure it's firewall issue ? any tests so that i can be sure it's due to firewall!!

Comment: You can use wireshark to observe the network traffic. Or you can have a look at your firewall logs to see if somethings filtered out. What is this '_nmx._tcp.local.' service? Is it running on a windows PC?

Comment: @RaphMclee, i tried it in local, no protection or firewall enabled accesspoint network. Still i didn't got the service being resolved!

Comment: @nmxprime did you ever find a fix?

Comment: @anakin78z, NO. I ended up implementing minimal mDNS myself